# How to pass variable into file path ini php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass $namefile into a path download. how to do it?

```
public function download($namefile)
        {
            
            return $this->response->download("pathfile/[here]", null);
        }
```

i'm using label to download the file

```
<label>File <a href="/suratmasuk/download/<?= $surat['file']; ?>"><sup>Download</sup></a></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to download a file using button?
If yes, why don't you use `<?php base_url()/[file location] ?>` inside your button href?

Comment: i'm using tag label to download the file but i dont know how to pass spesific name file